# Set ES5 class' property type using JSDoc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, javascript-intellisense, visual-studio-community

I have class that has a property:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.property = null;
    }
}
```

The property can be `null` or an `Array` instance. I tried this:

```
/**
 * @property property {Array}
 */
class MyClass ...
```

This:

```
/**
 * @property MyClass.property {Array}
 */
class MyClass ...
```

And this:

```
class MyClass {
    /**
     * @property property {Array}
     */
    constructor() ...
```

And I'm still seeing this in intellisense:

[image: <code>(property) MyClass.property: any</code>]

So can anyone tell me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, the best approach was this:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        /** @type {MyClass2} **/
        this.property = null;
    }
}
```

It still is kind of buggy but most of the time it works.

Comment: If the property is assigned from constructor parameter, then it's type can be inferred by Visual Studio (and Visual Studio Code).